# Attaching a document to a task

Tags: asana

I could not find a way of attaching a document to a task via the Asana API's at http://developers.asana.com

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

(I work at Asana)

Sorry, there is currently no way to add an attachment to a task via the API.

Answer (score 0):

While Greg was correct at the time he wrote this, I'm now pleased to say you can both fetch *and* upload attachments via the API: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/attachments